# Debug an running exe app that packed by zeit/pkg

Tags: node.js, debugging, zeit-pkg

Can I attach a debugger to a running NodeJS application that packed by [pkg](https://github.com/zeit/pkg)?
My new company has a packed console app without source code. It's worked fine in last year, but it has some small exception in this year.
It seems some exceptions happened because the old developer did not cover or hardcode the year variable. All exceptions mentioned c:\snapshot\xxx.js.

I guess we have a solution to recover their file and debug to it.
Anyone help me to find a debugger, or recover the source code? Can I fix it by IDA or ollydbg?

Thanks